# A colleague owes me money. How do I / should I claim it back?

Tags: colleagues, relationships

Some details:

- We're both young (<30 years) and university colleagues as well
- We bought something as a shared thing. It was my idea, but he agreed

I need the money back. How should I remind him, but without coming across as a poor person?

Comment: I'm not convinced this is a workplace question. It comes closer to being a personal finance question, but it's mostly an interpersonal problem.  The way you start getting the money is to ask for it. Hopefully you had your agreement in writing; if not it's more difficult to collect if they aren't inclined to cooperate. "Hey, we agreed to share the cost of this; I advanced the funds, but I need that cash; when are you going to pay your share". Next time get the money up front,  and remember that doing business with friends can be fatal to the friendship if you aren't VERY careful.

Comment: Are we talking 10 or 10000? That makes quite a difference. And include the denomination, this is an international site.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZomwVcGt0LE

Comment: Why haven't you asked him already? That may give some insight otherwise, it's something you learned in grade school.

Comment: This is about personal finance, not workplace.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about interpersonal relationships and nothing to do with the workplace.

Answer (score 7):

**Politely, firmly, and in a face-saving way.**

"Hey Colleague, remember that shared thing we bought a while back?  Did I give you my bank account details yet, so you could me wire your share?  Cash also works if that's easier for you."

Comment: Simple and easy. No need to complicate things.

Answer (score 2):

How you ask fairly depends on your relationship with your colleague.

Below are some of the fair strategies used in money sharing. Each of us would have separate preferences depending on the relationship and the amount of money involved.

1. You get one time, I get one time: For example it works good for coffee breaks. I pay this time, I expect(implicitly) you to pay the next time because I believe you are a fair person.
2. We share the expenses equally independent of the proportion bias: Happens in restaurant scenario's sometime.
3. We pay per use or share for what we eat: This happens typically in restaurant situations as each user have their own preference of food and the prices vary.

Depending on the relationship and the amount of money involved you could choose any of these strategies. It is OK to mention upfront to your colleague your preferred approach so that you could share amicable relationship with him.

If you both do not have a agreed strategy in place. You could either ask him to pay for your next buy with him or go ahead and say -

> Hey Bob,
>
> Could you give me your share of X$ for Y we bought the other day?